# Error in attaching entity when using singleton Repository and Unit of Work Pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, unit-of-work

Let's say I have `Book` and `Author` Domain Models,

```
public class Book {
  [Key]
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string BookName { get; set; }
  [ForeignKey="Author"]
  public int AuthorId {get; set;}
  public Author Author { get; set; }
}

public class Author {
  [Key]
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string AuthorName { get; set; }
  public string Country {get; set;}
}
```

I've seperated bussiness logic validation and crud, so I call my validation provider to validate the new entity in addBook service method.

```
//BookService.cs
public bool AddBook(AddBook addBook)
{
    // addBook = new { BookName = "Harry Potter", Author = new { Id = 2 } }
    this._validationProvider.Validate(addBook);
    var newBook = _mapper.Map<AddBook, Book>(addBook);
    // i need to get newBook.Author.Country, so attach it,
    _uow.Repository<Author>.Attach(addBook.Author); //<<<------ Exception is here
    //Exception "An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. 
    //The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key."
    _uow.Repository<Author>().Entry(addBook.Author).Reload();
}

//BookValidate.cs
public bool Validate(Addbook addBook)
{
    var author = _uow.Repository<Author>().GetById(addBook.Author.Id); //it's attached
    //checking author etc.
}
```

The problem is, I must attach `addBook.Author` in `AddBook` method, beacuse I don't know and don't mind what is happening in `Validate` method. That might be written by somebody else, it's a bussiness logic validation.

But in that bussiness logic validation method they've already attached the `addBook.Author` and I got the below error message,

How can I handle kind of this problem?

> Exception "An object with the same key already exists in the
>   ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple
>   objects with the same key."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the `Validate` method does not need to track the `Author` entry.
Please check in your Repository if it is possible to mark the query as no tracking.

In `EntityFramework` you can add the method `AsNoTracking()` to the `Linq` statement.

There are existing questions answered related to this issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ObjectStateManager+cannot+track+multiple+objects+

Comment: "In general, the Validate method does not need to track the Author entry", this is the solution what I actually follow. Yes, validate method just uses author for only one property, so I ended up query with anonymous object. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I can see that you only need author as a reference by Id. So you only need to set Book.AuthorId property...not Book.Author.Id ...

addBook = new { BookName = "Harry Potter", AuthorId = 2 }

This resolve your problem and keep your logic accurate with what really you want.

Also you can change Attach by Entry.

Business

```
 _uow.Repository<Author>.Entry(addBook.Author);
```

Repository

```
Entry<T>(T entity)
{
    this.context.Entry(entity).EntityState = EntityState.Unchanged
}
```

Comment: I thought about, that would be great but I need author as a reference in AddBook method, I didn't shared all of my code, but as I added code-comment, I need to get newBook.Author.Country and updating some other tables base on that value.

Comment: So if your problem is the attach method you can use context.Entry(book.author).EntityState = Unchanged. This approach doesn't throw exception and warranty that the author exists in the context.